# loop over years and months

Tags: r, loops, date

I need to loop over a list of dates and extract the number of days in each month (in a year).
I didn't find a way to loop over months and years in r, is there a way to do it?

adding part of my list as an example:

```
dates<-as.Date(c("2014-11-07" ,"2014-11-08","2014-11-09", "2014-11-10" ,
"2014-11-11" ,"2014-11-12" ,"2014-11-13" ,"2014-11-14", "2014-12-01",
"2014-12-02" ,"2014-12-03","2014-12-04", "2014-12-20" ,"2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-22","2015-01-01" ,"2015-01-02" ,"2015-01-03" ,"2015-01-04" ,
"2015-01-05"))
```

Thanks

Comment: `lubridate` perhaps?

Comment: Could you share your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use format to get the years and count, i.e.

```
i1 <- format(dates, format = '%Y')
table(i1)
#2014 2015 
#  15    5
```

To do it per month, per year,

```
table(format(dates, format = '%Y/%m'))

#2014/11 2014/12 2015/01 
#      8       7       5
```

Comment: You prefer `tapply(i1, i1, length)` over `table(i1)`? @Sotos

Comment: hahaha...of course not. I just forgot about `table`. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought of `tapply` and `lengths(split(i1, i1))` LOL...gotta love Mondays

Comment: thanks allot! with: format (dates, format ='%Y-%m') it was exactly what I needed!